# Stockfish does the same moves everytime for a given postition

Tags: python, chess, python-chess, stockfish

Using stockfish for a chess program. It gives the same moves every time for any position. It even opens with the same moves.

I'm using the python-chess library for communicating with stockfish I'm not sure if that's where the issue lies or if it's something else.

```
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(
        r"engine/stockfish_14.1_win_x64_popcnt/stockfish_14.1_win_x64_popcnt.exe")
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you expect it to make different moves in the same position?

Comment: Is that not supposed to happen? Engines usually don't do the same moves every time? I couldn't find any details or docs regarding this.

Comment: I don't know if it is supposed to happen, but it stands to reason that it might be what's supposed to happen, since there is presumably one move in each position that the engine thinks is best. That's why I asked if you had a reason to expect otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense but chess engines that players play against like on chess.com play various moves, especially in the opening. I realize that this may not be an inbuilt feature of the engine itself, is there a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Stockfish plays the move it thinks is best in any given position. That is why it will always give you the same move if you feed it the same position and give it the same amount to think.

In engine vs engine tournaments they often play according to given opening positions. The first X moves are therefore given and then the engines will play on from there by themselves. This way the games will be different most of the times, otherwise the games would look the same no matter how many times they played.

Comment: Yes, that's true but engines that players play against like on chess.com play various moves, especially in the opening. I realize that this may not be an inbuilt feature of the engine itself, is there a good way to implement this?

Comment: Engines on sites are often inferior versions of the main engine to make play more fun. One way to get this behavior yourself is to use an opening book for the engine and make it chose random openings from that. If the opening book is large enough you will get different games each time without having to mess around with the main search code. You can read more on opening books here: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Opening_Book.

Answer (score 0):

Chess engines like Stockfish try to play the best move for a given position. The move found by an engine depends mainly on time constraints and number of threads searching - if those parameters are the same, you can expect the returned best move to be the same - especially when the engine is searching on a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

About the OP's comment

" chess engines that players play against like on chess.com play various moves, especially in the opening. I realize that this may not be an inbuilt feature of the engine itself, is there a good way to implement this? "

You could pass `multipv` option, like

```
variations = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1), multipv=5)
```

maybe eliminate blunders (set e.g. `thresh = 100` and decrese to make engine play stronger)

```
variations = [info for info in variations if
        variations[0]['score'].relative.score() - info['score'].relative.score() < thresh]
```

and pick a move at random

```
move = random.choice(variations)['pv'][0]
```

This way you wouldn't have to mess with opening books and you can throttle the strength of the engine a bit :)

Ok, I'm going to test it now, to see what value of `thresh` I can beat ...